# UnsupportedClassVersionError deploying EJB "HelloWord" in Glasshfish 3

Tags: eclipse, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3, web-deployment

I try to deploy a simple "Hello Word" in my local server GlasshFish 3, but at the deploy the console print this message

```
[#|2013-01-15T15:00:02.458+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|
javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.Exception while deploying the app
[HelloWorldEJB] :UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class ejb_other.PlaceAuctionItemBean 
as unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found 
in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.6.0_27|#]
```

My JAVA_HOME has java version 1.6.0_27 (it refers to _C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27_), my Eclipse (indigo) project refers to java 1.6.0_27.
I *think* (i don't know how to verify) that GlasshFish refers to JAVA_HOME.

In my PC (Windows 7) I found 2 directory having **java.exe**:

- *C:\Windows\SysWOW64*>java -version -->>java version "1.6.0_29"
- *C:\Windows\System32*>java -version -->>java version "1.6.0_27"

I found more discussions about this exception (f.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239086/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) ), but I need of something more specific for Eclipse/Glasshfish, because I can't to solve. I see that the JVM is the same for compilation and execution.

### Post Scriptim

I add the screenshot about the places where I declare JVM: it's always 1.6.
one:[image: compiler]
two:[image: build path eclipse]
three:[image: envieronment variables]

Where can I see that I compile with java 7 or it runs with another JVM?

Comment: solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540548/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-use-a-different-compiler-version-for-java. I had'nt found this answer before. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution

There's another place where setting the compiler's options:

[how do I get eclipse to use a different compiler version for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540548/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-use-a-different-compiler-version-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

`ejb_other.PlaceAuctionItemBean` was obviously compiled for Java 7 which won't work if you run it in a Java 6 JVM.

Comment: ok, I added screenshot where I se that I compile with Java 6. Where am I wrong?

Comment: solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540548/how-do-i-get-eclipse-to-use-a-different-compiler-version-for-java. Maybe my question is a duplicate...