# Java application is not able to find JDK 1.7 on Mac (Installer created with install4j)

Tags: macos, java-7, install4j

I have created a Java application installer *using install4j for Mac OS X*. My application uses *JDK 1.7*.

I have set the JDK version in install4j properly as well.

I have also installed JDK 1.7 on Mac and when I type `java -version` command on console it gives me JDK 1.7.

Application also installed successfully but I am out of luck, *when I try to start the application it gives me this error*:

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: a (Unsupporte d major.minor version 51.0)

The above error occurs because it uses Apple's inbuilt JDK 1.6. I want app to use JDK 1.7 which is already installed on the machine.

## Edit

Now I have created installer by selecting OpenJdk in jre option.
Now it is not giving me the **UnsupportedClassVersionError** but now application icon blinks on the dockbar and goes.

Below is the cosole log.

5/23/13 11:16:47.777 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[154]: ([0x0-0x92092].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[800]) Exited with code: 1
5/23/13 11:17:09.166 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[154]: ([0x0-0x93093].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[802]) Exited with code: 1
5/23/13 11:17:12.400 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[154]: ([0x0-0x94094].com.install4j.9409-6211-0940-9008.25[804]) Exited with code: 1

Please help me.

Comment: [This may help you to solve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239086/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the media file wizard for your Mac OS X installer, go to the "JRE" step and select "Installed OpenJDK JRE (Java 7 and higher)".

Comment: If you do this, it's not possible that the installer and the launchers use the Apple 1.6 JDK, so this must be a different problem.

Comment: I have not installed Open JDK 1.7 I have installed Oracle JDK 1.7.

Comment: Yes, that is effectively OpenJDK (as compared to Apple JDK).

Comment: So, what should I do to run it on Oracle JDK 1.7 because I don't want to use Open JDK 1.7.

Comment: When you say "OpenJDK" on Mac OS X what is effectively meant is Oracle JDK. Oracle JDK is basically the same as OpenJDK. And my answer says what you have to do to run it with Oracle JDK.