# Haskell Plugin on Eclipse is not visible

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-plugin

I'm learning Haskell and I need to install Haskell plugin on Eclipse.
I have first installed Eclipse Kepler and then installed the Haskell plugin from http://eclipsefp.sf.net/updates. The plugin installation went ok but the Haskell perspective is not visible at Window > Open Perspective > Other. It's visible at Help > Installation Details, though.

I've come across similar problem at this post:
[Plugins installed on Eclipse not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697882/plugins-installed-on-eclipse-not-visible)

I've applied all suggestions: I've started Eclipse as root, I've changed the installation path from /Applications to ~/, I've given write access to plugins folder, no luck.

I've erased Eclipse Kepler and installed Luna, still no luck.
I've updated the JRE to Java SE 7 [1.7.0_71] and edited the Java JRE section at Eclipse preferences, still no luck.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.
My OS X Lion 10.7.4 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. The problem seems to stem from multiple java versions installed on Lion. 
I've come across this post [salesforce Eclipse plugin](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AbEjIAK) and there I noticed that multiple Java versions on one system might cause trouble on plugins and in case of saleforce, that was causing trouble on Eclipse plugin or perspective.

Then I've taken a second look at Haskell's Eclipse plugin page [Haskell Eclipse plugin](http://eclipsefp.github.io/install.html#extra) and there I saw the java version 7 was emphasized.

So I reckoned that some java version mismatch might be causing Eclipse not to display the Haskell plugin. Btw, my installing the latest (1.7.0_72) version of java didn't change any possibel version mismatch on my Mac OS X, because though I successfully installed 1.7.0_72 version (using the file jdk-7u72-macosx-x64.dmg which I downloaded from oracle.com), the $ javac -version still returned 1.6.0_29.

Then I've found this post [multiple java installations on mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147720/multiple-java-installations-in-mac-os-x-mavericks) and added the following line to eclipse.ini

-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

before -vmargs, and that finally solved the problem. Now the Haskell plugin and perspective comes up. That's fine.