# Unable to deploy war in tomcat 6.0.24 on linux server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

We are tring to upload the war of our jsp servlet project named demo_nfc.war,but We are getting the below error while deploying war file.

```
==========================
Jul 25, 2014 3:07:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive demo_nfc.war
Jul 25, 2014 3:07:53 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo_nfc/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 25, 2014 3:07:53 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo_nfc/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-3.0.20090124.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 25, 2014 3:07:53 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/demo_nfc/WEB-INF/lib/servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jul 25, 2014 3:07:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry registerComponent
SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=JspMonitor,name=jsp,WebModule=//localhost/demo_nfc,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
Jul 25, 2014 3:07:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive demo_nfc.war
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/servlet/AdminController : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.servlet.AdminController)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2335)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:976)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1451)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1074)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4377)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:593)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
==========================
```

but when we deploy war with single jsp file it deployed successfully.

Comment: You're mixing JAR files compiled for one version of Java with JAR files compiled for another. "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.servlet.AdminController)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239086/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have compiler your project is java 7, exported the WAR and now trying to deploy it is tomcat container which is using Java 6 runtime.

So either configure your tomcat to use Java 6 runtime or build your war again with Java 7.