# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 - grails

Tags: java, grails, java-7

I just downloaded a grails project from svn.

I saw that the unsupported major.minor version is a [well known problem on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11239128/1948785) caused by a mismatch version of JDK used during runtime and compile time.

But I am using the very same version as below:

shell:

[image]

JAVA Build Path:

[image]

Installed JRE:

[image]

Please what am I missing for still having the below error?

```
Environment set to development
  [groovyc] Compiling 190 source files to C:\Users\xxx
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:117)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:104)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:69)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:85)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:84)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:28)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.findJavac(JavacJavaCompiler.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.compile(JavacJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit.gotoPhase(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:484)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:453)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:905)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:607)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    ... 23 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.findJavac(JavacJavaCompiler.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.compile(JavacJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit.gotoPhase(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:484)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:453)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:180)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:905)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:607)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:117)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:104)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:69)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:85)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:84)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:28)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Compilation error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I run it via rightclick on project -> run-as -> grailsCommand (run-app)

Comment: It wants Java 8, not Java 7.

Comment: @Kayaman, thanks for your response. why do u say that? The developer that committed this project on svn is targeting it to jdk7. why are u saying 8?

Comment: and the grails version is 1.3.7

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` tells the whole story. The class `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` has version `52.0` (i.e. java 8). Obviously your developer didn't build and commit that class, but your Gradle is probably using the Java 8 tools, causing this problem when you're trying to build using Java 7.

Comment: Could you share the project URL?

Comment: it's a local project which is run via rightclick->run-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the appropriate groovy version for grails version I have.
You can find the link [here](https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/14/list-of-groovy-versions-for-each-version-of-grails/).
For instance, grails 2.3.9 -> groovy 2.1.9

I also made sure to use the right Java version based on `grails.project.target.level` in `BuildConfig.groovy`. For me, it is 1.7 (java 7)

Answer (score 4):

The project was compiled using a newer version of JDK but is being run at an older version. Clean all your code and rebuild the project.

Sometimes this is due to a plugin whose binary has been compiled with a higher version of Java.