# SOAPUI 5.6. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

Tags: soapui, linux-mint

Linux Mint 20.2, java 1.8.0

I install SoapUI 5.6 from official site.

But when I try to start

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/eviware/soapui/SoapUI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:81)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:62)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/3355860 https://stackoverflow.com/a/11239128/3355860

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: @SiKing yes, thanks