# Java Error: Could not find or load main class. (Eclipse Juno) with package

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, package

So I made a project with packages in Eclipse.
I have a few classes all in same package com.example.parser.
In Eclipse everything works fine. 
So I wanted to run one of the class from command line.
The java/javac PATHs are set correctly and work normally if no packages are there.
The file structure looks like this:

```
~Project/bin/com/example/parser/*.class (all class files)
~Project/src/com/example/parser/*.java (all source files)
```

So in command line I go to ~Project/bin/com/example/parser 
To mention OS: Windows 7 Pro
The command java ClassToRun gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClassToRun (wrong name:
com/example/parser/ClassToRun) at ... (stack trace)
```

So I googled a bit and got to conclusion this is the correct command:
java -cp .;~Project/bin ClassToRun
Now I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ~Project/bin
```

So I could not solve this... any one can help a bit?
PS: Forgot to mention the "/" should be "\" and the "~" stands for the abs path infront.
Oh yeah and I just update to jdk 1.7...

Comment: There's a few ways this could go wrong, and a few details missing.  The devil may be in the details here.  Consider providing current working dir and command lines.

Comment: @RichardSitze: I think the devil here is a couple of missing double quotes, along with the special importance of the semicolon for the Windows command prompt...

Comment: @thkala: comment made under your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you type the fully-qualified class name at the command prompt?

i.e.

```
java -cp .;~Project\bin name.of.package.Class
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip... after whole the night I did setting up my java environment this never crossed my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

`.metadata` is corrupted.

Steps:

```
Stop eclipse, delete .metadata in workspace and restart eclipse

Import Project

Run again
```

([Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356854/eclipse-cant-find-load-main-class))