# Eclipse not responding

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7

Was working fine yesterday, overnight Windows 7 rebooted, now Eclipse won't finish loading - spinner displayed with "Eclipse SDK (Not Responding)" 
Dialog "User Operation is Waiting" for "Building workspace" to complete.
Android SDK Content Loader remains at 0%
I have tried:

- eclipse - clean
  delete C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

Here's the top of the Log file, which I cannot interpret.
Any help would be gratefully received.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-26 16:02:09.250
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer", thread "Thread[Worker-0,5,main]" timed out waiting (5008ms) for thread "Thread[main,6,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 [200]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-0,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:../../Users/Cats PC/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1709980481/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar" by thread "main".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2845)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2821)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2844)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$11.run(JavaModelManager.java:2769)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2809)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1872)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:3556)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 30 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2845)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2821)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2844)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$11.run(JavaModelManager.java:2769)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2809)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1872)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:3556)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-04-26 16:02:09.495
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer", thread "Thread[Worker-4,5,main]" timed out waiting (5000ms) for thread "Thread[main,6,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 [200]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Worker-4,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:../../Users/Cats PC/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_1709980481/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.jar" by thread "main".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.computeClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2845)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainerInitializer(JavaCore.java:2821)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2844)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$11.run(JavaModelManager.java:2769)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2809)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1872)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2798)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2674)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2838)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1943)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.validateClasspaths(DeltaProcessor.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessor.java:2098)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessingState.resourceChanged(DeltaProcessingState.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastBuildEvent(Workspace.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 42 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse can't find / load main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356854/eclipse-cant-find-load-main-class)

Answer (score 2):

In the .metadata.plugins directory, search for files with "snap" in the name (e.g. .snap, .markers.snap, .syncinfo.snap, etc.).  When I stopped Eclipse and deleted all of these files, Eclipse then started normally on restart.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me when I updated the Android SDK-Tools a couple of days ago. I ended up downloading Eclipse again and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, after spending more than a day messing around searching for suggestions and trying things was as follows:

- Close Eclipse.
- with WIndows Explorer, make a copy of copy the workspace folder (not used, but just in case!)
- In the workspace folder, delete the  .metadata folder
- Re-start Eclipse (now has no projects)
- Import the projects one by one with file->Import->General->"Existing Projects Into Workspace (**NOT Android->"Existing Android Code into Workspace"**). You can import the projects from the existing workspace folder.

I had a the Google Maps library, "google-play-services_lib" which I imported as Android->"Existing Android Code into Workspace"
It's now all back up and running.
I can only assume that something in the .metadata labyrintyh (35 Mb of obscure folders and files!) became corrupted during  the overnight Windows reboot to install M$ updates.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a project you imported externally(outside of **Workspace**), that may cause this problem. If you can access Eclipse try to remove it. If you are getting the '**No responding at startup**', then go delete the file at source.

This will solve the problem.