# Java Classes with small letter name in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I made one simple following class in Eclipse:

```
package Practice;

public class smallLetterClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        smallLetterClass fp=new smallLetterClass();
        fp.flip();

    }

    public void flip(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

}
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Practice.smallLetterClass, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Though I was able to resolve it by making Java class name starting with capital letter. Can anyone help in understanding what exactly happened here?

Comment: how you run this code, it work fine with me

Comment: This ran fine for me too. Though, why are you deliberately naming packages and classes in a way that is not recommended? You should follow [standard naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Comment: I am using Neon Eclipse with Java 8. I am running it normally as 'Run as Java application'

Comment: I did that by mistake, did not intend to! but was wondering on the exception

Comment: It runs fine. Something is somehow out of sync: either you haven't saved it, or you have refactored it with the proper naming and are still trying to run it with the old name, or something. So it runs, but you just shouldn't do this at all. The only relationship between the errors you are seeing and the class name is coincidental.

Comment: @James_D which version of eclipse and java you are using?

Comment: It makes no difference. I ran that on jdk1.8.0_121, Eclipse Mars.1

Comment: I made multiple versions on Neon, still the same exception. I ran it through MyEclipse(Java 6) it ran successfully, probably I am missing something

PS: I even tried making a new project (dynamic web project) in Neon and tried the same code, got the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running it as a `Java Application`? If so, try cleaning the project.

```
Project > Clean... > OK
```

If it doesn't help, it means your `.metadata` folder is corrupted. [See this post for resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10356854/7709086).

Comment: But It ran as soon i refactor it to SmallLetterClass.

Comment: Cleaned and tried , got same exception.
**Error: Main method not found in class Practice.smallLetterClass, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application**