# I have enabled the "Build Automatically" option in eclipse, still it is not generating the class files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried refresh, clean and also "build project" . Still class files are not being generated.

The exact error is " A cycle was detected in the build path of project_1 The cycle consists of Proj_2,Proj_3 etc"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Feel free to restart the eclipse.

Comment: what is project nature, where are you looking for .class file, what event you made and you are expecting build trigger ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A build cycle is when you have cyclic dependencies, e.g. proj_1 needs proj_2, proj_2 needs proj_3 and proj_3 needs proj_1 again. When building, eclipse uses the dependency information to determine which projects to build first, but when there are cyclic dependencies, it cannot decide.

See if you can break the cycle, e.g. in this case by removing proj_1 from the build path of proj_3. Maybe you need to move some classes to a different project so you don't need the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

right click on project (for maven project) > java build path > check source folder, there you will see source folder and corresponding output folder where your classes will reside, if this is not there then your build will not create classes.. or java project check in bin folder as said by vijay

i found this stack link for you, check this

[A cycle was detected in the build path of project xxx - Build Path Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084866/a-cycle-was-detected-in-the-build-path-of-project-xxx-build-path-problem)

or you can change cyclic dependency severity level to warning, check below

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t71727.html

Answer (score 1):

try this, Open up Project->Properties and select Java Build Path from the list. In the Libraries tab you'll see a button labeled "Add Class Folder..." Point that to the location of your .class file. check each tab to see if there are any build path problems.. then refresh or restart the eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

*go to project menu ..select the build automatically option.
go to project source folder, then look for bin folder you might hava .class files there.*